# ¿Como obtener el value y el id de un select multiple con JS o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Explico tengo un `select multiple`, en el cual se despliegan `options` con diferentes valores, entre los atributos que necesito rescatar son los `id` y los `value`, de los campos seleccionados, que son distintos, había probado con:

```
var segr_value = $("#segr_name").val();
```

El cual funciona, pero solamente me trae los atributos del `value`

Para obtener ahora el `id` había probado:

```
var segr_id = $("#segr_name").children(":selected").attr("id");
```

Pero solamente me devuelve un valor, en caso de seleccionar muchos valores.

Agradezco de ante mano, su ayuda por favor

```
   <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="segr_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Grupo de Servicio(*)</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">

                                    <select id="segr_name" name="segr_name" data-size="2" data-width="100%"
                                        class="selectpicker" multiple data-value="{{segr_name}}"
                                        title="Seleccione Grupo de Servicio">
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo utilizando [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) sobre el resultado de `$("#segr_name").children(":selected")`

#### Ejemplo

```js
let $select = $('#segr_name');
$select.on('change', () => {
  let selecteds = [];

  // Buscamos los option seleccionados
  $select.children(':selected').each((idx, el) => {
    // Obtenemos los atributos que necesitamos
    selecteds.push({
      id: el.id,
      value: el.value
    });
  });
  
  //
  console.log(selecteds);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="segr_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Grupo de Servicio(*)</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select id="segr_name" name="segr_name" data-size="2" data-width="100%" class="selectpicker" multiple data-value="{{segr_name}}" title="Seleccione Grupo de Servicio">
      <option id="opt1" value="1">1</option>
      <option id="opt2" value="2">2</option>
      <option id="opt3" value="3">3</option>
      <option id="opt4" value="4">4</option>      
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opcion es cambiar el selector a `"#segr_name :selected"` y usar `.map()` sobre esos valores, ejemplo:

```js
$("#enviar").click(function() {

  const ids = [...$("#segr_name :selected")].map(e => e.id);

  console.log(ids)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="segr_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Grupo de Servicio(*)</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select id="segr_name" name="segr_name" data-size="2" data-width="100%" class="selectpicker" multiple data-value="{{segr_name}}" title="Seleccione Grupo de Servicio">
      <option id="uno">1</option>
      <option id="dos">2</option>
      <option id="tres">3</option>
      <option id="cuatro">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```